# Library not loaded - ogr2ogr - topojson (Mike Bostock's d3.js map tutorial)

Tags: gdal, topojson

I'm trying to use ogr2ogr to filter a shapefile. I'm working through Mike Bostock's [Let's Make a Map tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). A bit of googling - including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472493/ogr2ogr-error-in-mac-os-10-8) - hasn't led to any solutions yet. I'm also VERY new to topojson (and shapefiles in general; my background is in economics/statistical software like Stata), so I'm not sure what I'm doing and where things are going wrong. Either way - here's the error result I'm getting:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/libspatialite/4.1.1/lib/libspatialite.5.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

No idea what liblwgeom-2.1.1.dylib is, what it does, where I get it, etc. Google hasn't helped much on defining it either.

FWIW, I'm on a Mac, I brew installed npm and gdal, and then npm installed topojson.

Thanks,

a

**Edited to add**: I just brew reinstalled gdal, because I remembered getting a warning (Caveats). See below:

```
==> Caveats
For non-homebrew python (2.x), you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
This version of GDAL was built with Python support. In addition to providing
modules that makes GDAL functions available to Python scripts, the Python
binding provides additional command line tools.
```

I actually tried to run `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH` literally as-is, and it returned nothing. (Not sure if something happened in the background?) Basically fumbling in the dark!

Comment: I have been using [KyngChaos frameworks](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks), including GDAL for many years without problems. It installs everything under `/Library/Frameworks/`.

Comment: Thanks, Lars. I've DLed the GDAL 1.10 Complete KyngChaos framework, and installed both GDAL and NumPy. Just fired up terminal and tried to re-run my problematic code from the tutorial: `ogr2ogr \
  -f GeoJSON \
  -where "adm0_a3 IN ('GBR', 'IRL')" \
  subunits.json \
  ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp` But I'm still getting the same error message as above. I suspect it may be something as simple as moving something from one folder to another (something I don't know how to do yet in Terminal).

Comment: Maybe you are still using the gdal you installed before? If you type `which ogr2ogr` it should point to: `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr`. If not, you may want to uninstall the gdal version you installed with brew.

Comment: Thanks, cengel. Argh. Uninstalled gdal, and installed the KyngChaos framework. But `which ogr2ogr` turns up nothing. Searched through Finder, and it's definitely there - i.e. I have `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr`, but - for whatever reason - Terminal's not seeing it.

Comment: As temporary workaround set the path in the terminal with `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Programs:$PATH`. Then, in the same terminal, type your ogr2ogr command. For a more permanent solution see for example [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106823).

Comment: Thanks, cengel. This worked for me, after editing your command to the specific filepath: `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH` After running this, I checked `which ogr2ogr` (which worked) and ran my ogr2ogr command as well (which sort of worked - it broke, but for another reason). Inch by inch, it seems! Thanks again.